# Adding functions to STDClass

Tags: php

This is something that has been bugging me for a while and today I found a relatively easy solution that I thought I'd share as I couldn't seem to find any decent answer.

I have this code for my DB wrapper:

```
function find($id) {
    //Fetch the results
    //Put the results into an array

    return (object) $results;
}
```

So I could do:

```
$result = DB::find(1);
echo $result->name; #=> Hello world
```

But I need to be able to assign methods to that new result. In this case `to_json`

Comment: why cant you just pass $result to `json_encode`?

Comment: This isn't about the `to_json` function. It's about being able to implement functions that the $results variable can use.

Comment: That was a crappy explanation sorry. For example you could implement this in future: http://pastebin.com/swuf3rEi The save() function would not have been previously possible.

Comment: there is no *sane* way of adding methods to an instance in PHP. If you need a save or toJson or whatever method, write a class.

Comment: Which I did.. read the answer :p

Comment: ooh, this is a self answered question. my bad.

Comment: Haha yes sorry if I didn't make that clear

Answer (score 1):

You can do so like this:

```
class Result {
    protected $results;

    public function __construct($results) {
        $this->results = $results;

        foreach($results as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value; 
        }
    }

    public function to_json() {
        return json_encode($this->results);
    }
}
```

Now instead of returning `return (object) $result` just do: `return new Result($result);`

```
$result = DB::find(1);
echo $result->name;      #=> Hello world
echo $result->to_json(); #=> {"name":"Hello world","content":"Hello World!"}
```